# have challenges uploading csv file into R

Tags: r

I have some challenges loading olympa.csv file into R. I do not know what is the problem because I was able to load others csv files.This the error I have while try to upload CSV file into R. Thank you

```
olym = read.table("olympa.csv",header=T)


Error in read.table("olympa.csv", header = T) : 
  more columns than column names
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the CSV file? Sometimes the way the columns are separated can do this like if your file uses comma as separator.
To resolve it you can just change the read.table to:
olym = read.table("olympa.csv",header=T,sep=",")